# BitLocker on Windows 8.1 (Surface Pro 3) won't complete

Tags: windows-8, usb, encryption, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I started encrypting a large USB drive on PC running Windows 10 and wanted to continue it on Surface Pro 3 running Windows 8.1

When I resume encryption on Surface Pro 3, nothing happens to the drive, after some time it seems to go to sleep.

I checked Power Settings and Device Manager and ensured that USB ports wouldn't be switched off automatically.

Any idea of how to finish encryption using Surface Pro 3?

Comment: You can't.  You would have to, cancel the operation on the Windows 10 PC, then restart the process on the Surface Pro 3

Comment: @Ramhound thank you, I should have checked it before starting the encryption. Can I disable BitLocker for the drive on Surface Pro 3?

Comment: At this stage you would have to finish the encryption process, if there is data on the drive, because it can't be decrypted until the process is finished.  This assume that by doing what you have done, has not prevented, the encryption process from being able to be completed.  It all depends on what confirmation prompts you confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was able to complete the encryption on a different machine.
The only requirement was having the same OS installed.

Once I found another Windows 10 machine, the encryption proceeded.

This means, if you start BitLocker encryption on Windows 10 machine, you must use the same machine or other machine if it has Windows 10 installed.